# 成语 and 俗语 emphasizing adaptation

Tags: idioms, chengyu

I would like to know what chinese 成语 or 俗语 can be used to emphasize the need of people or generations to adapt to the given situation or environment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> *people or generations to adapt to the given situation or environment*

1. 靠山吃山，靠海吃海

> People who live near mountains make a living in the mountains,  people who live near the sea make a living in the sea

Notice: 靠 here doesn't mean depend on. It means lean against = near; close to

2. [因地制宜](https://pedia.cloud.edu.tw/Entry/Detail/?title=%E5%9B%A0%E5%9C%B0%E5%88%B6%E5%AE%9C)

> 根據環境的實際情況制定相應的辦法 - Formulate corresponding measures according to the actual situation of the environment

When a group migrated to a new place, they have to adapt to the environment and adjust their way of life. That's 因地制宜.

For personal situation:

[執生](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%89%A7%E7%94%9F/3577001)

> 何谓执生: 简单而言，就是「随机应变」，「伺机行事」。即在事前没有准备或临时有变时，要懂得灵活异变。

> To put it simply, it means "acting according to circumstances" and "waiting for opportunities." That is, when there is no preparation beforehand or when there is a temporary change, you must know how to be flexible and make necessary changes.

執 = hold = be mindful of

生 = unfamiliar (element)

執生 = caution and prepare to react

~

穷则变，变则通

Adapt when options are exhausted. The problem will be solved if you adapt

Comment: #1 reminds me of 林中不买新，湖上不鬻鱼

Answer (score 0):

> 入乡随俗 ru4 xiang1 sui2 su2

is close in meaning to "When in Rome, do as the Romans do"

Answer (score 0):

"适者生存", similar to "survival of the fittest".

"嫁鸡随鸡, 嫁狗随狗", either accept, or adapt to, your fate/live in the future, after choosing/marring your spouse.

Answer (score 0):

随机应变

情况有变，我们就该随机应变。
As the situation changes, we too should adapt.

随遇而安

你应该随遇而安。
You should adapt to changing circumstances.

通变达权

做理能适应客观情况的变化，懂得变通，不死守常规。
The wise can adapt to changes,

懂得变通，
understand flexibility,

不死守常规。
cling not to (old) custom.